# (Android) D/OkHttp: 400 Bad Request

Tags: android, api, request, rxjava, okhttp

```
@Headers("Authorization: " + BuildConfig.CLIENT_ID + " " + BuildConfig.CLIENT_SECRET)
@GET("get/list")
Observable<List<Post>> getList();
```

В каталоге выше т.е. в "get", лежит .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
AuthName "Staff Only:3"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile .../api/get/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

Внутри "get/list" нет прописанного случая, когда скрипт выдаёт ошибку 400. Да и, просто открытая api страница возвращает корректный Json (проверено на jsonschema2pojo.org). 
Также обязан отметить, что отсутствие header'а в представленном виде выше или внутри самого метода, также влияет на возвращаемый код ошибки - на 401 (что очевидно).

Но вот на это всё, okhttp какого-то хрена выдаёт следующее:

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://*********/api/get/list http/1.1
D/OkHttp: Authorization: r*******m *******6
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
...
D/OkHttp: <-- 400 Bad Request http://*********/api/get/list (18711ms)
D/OkHttp: Date: Sun, 19 Mar 2017 20:13:11 GMT
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 177
D/OkHttp: Connection: close
D/OkHttp: Server: -nginx
D/OkHttp: CF-RAY: -
D/OkHttp: <html>
D/OkHttp: <head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
D/OkHttp: <body bgcolor="white">
D/OkHttp: <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
D/OkHttp: <hr><center>cloudflare-nginx</center>
D/OkHttp: </body>
D/OkHttp: </html>
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (177-byte body)
```

Если проблема в том, что сервер сам закрывается из за большого объема данных, тогда почему в браузере всё ок? Если не в этом проблема, тогда в чём?

Comment: Почему ваш сервер возвращает `Content-Type: text/html`, а не `Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8`?

Comment: Mit, собственно то, весь пост выше и посвещен данному вопросу. Поче

Comment: В таком случае, где серверный код? Ответ дает сервер, а вы приводите логи с клиента и кусок клиентского кода.

Comment: Что-то вроде:
`<?php $mysqli -> ... <get database> ... -> $r -> echo json_encode($r);?>`
Ну ещё там фрагмент `if num_rows == 0 then header(404 not found)`
Не больше, не меньше
Это даже очевидно.. банальна.. а тут и пояснять надо:D